# Как вывести массив с помощью указателей?

Tags: c

Вот код, он не работает, какие еще есть варианты?

```
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3}, i;
int *f = a;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf(" %d", *f[i]);
}
```

И можно ли явно присвоить значения массиву  после его объявления? Т.е.

```
int a[3];

a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: @Alexandr Для форматирования кода, нужно выделить его мышкой и нажать на кнопку 101010.

Comment: @Alexandr Вам нужно принять тот ответ на вопрос, который лучшим образом решает проблему.

Comment: во первых в указателе хранится адрес первого элемента массива
int *f=&a[0];
во вторых
printf(" %d", f[i]);

Comment: @Сергей, ловко Вы подметили. Осталось только уточнить, что &a[0] == a всегда и везде.

Comment: @Alexandr кстати, обратите внимание на то, что Вы могли явно не указывать размер массива. int a[] = {1,2,3} тоже сработает.

Answer (score 3):

Можно. Также

```
int a[3]
```

и

```
int * f;
```

Одно и тоже. Ошибка в работе с указателем. Думаю проще представить два вида правильного кода и вы поймете, где прячется правда.

```
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3}, i;
int *f = a;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf(" %d", f[i]);
}
```

Второй вариант

```
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3}, i;
int *f = a;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf(" %d", *(f+i));
}
```

Comment: про i[f] не забудь

Answer (score 1):

Вот так работает.

```
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
int *f = a;
for(int i = 0; i <3; i++)
    printf("%d\n",f[i]);
return 0;
```

Вторым способом сделать нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int a[3] = {1, 2, 3}, i;
 int *f = a;

 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
     printf("%d \n", *f++);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот ещё вариант:

```
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3}, i;
int (*f)[] = &a;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) printf("%d ", (*f)[i]);
```

---

> И можно ли явно присвоить значения массиву после его объявления? Т.е.
>
> ```
> int a[3];
>
> a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
> ```

Нельзя по двум причинам:

1. `a[3]` - указывает на 4-й элемент массива (нумерация с нуля), а их объявлено (`int a[3]`) только три.
2. `int a[3]` объявляет массив чисел типа **int**, а в записи `a[3] = {1, 2, 3};` происходит попытка присваивания значения не типа **int**.